# Kirchhoff's laws for multiple loops

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits

My book (Knight, *Physics for Scientists and Engineers*) has a worked example with the following circuit:

[image]

Applying the loop law to the left loop, going clockwise, the author gets:

$$19 V - (300 \Omega)I_{1} - (100 \Omega) I_{3} - 12 V = 0$$

That makes sense to me, but to the right loop, they get:

$$12 V + (100 \Omega)I_{3} - (200 \Omega)I_{2} = 0$$

**The 12 V battery is traversed positive to negative, so why is it 12 V here rather than -12 V?** If you switch the sign of just that one element, the answer changes. Is there some other rule with batteries?

Comment: If you go around the right-hand loop clockwise, you traverse the 12-V battery negative to positive, not positive to negative.

Comment: But the current $I_{3}$ is going downward through the $100 \Omega$ resistor. I thought the sign depends on which way you're going relative to the current?

Comment: And you should not be deleting old questions of the same topic and asking very similar questions anew. You should be editing the old questions to make them good questions, and then people will reopen them.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Point taken. Will do.

Comment: No, the going "relative to the current" applies to the resistor (and other elements). For batteries, the voltage differences are already well-determined beforehand. Also, I would have avoided this loop, going instead for the 19V and avoiding 12V, so that you get a set of solvable equations. After that, you can study this particular loop and show that the scheme we are teaching you is correct.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Thank you. But what do you mean by the voltage being well-determined beforehand? The book states that going from positive-to-negative for a battery results in a negative value for the potential difference. Why, for a battery, is the key thing the direction you go around the loop rather than the direction of the current itself? That's what's confusing me.

Comment: A battery directly sets up a voltage difference in the way that it does. There is no current multiplied by anything when you traverse it, so it is independent of the direction you chose of the current. You can reason similarly for the other stuff: capacitors will also not be dependent upon current, but will depend upon the choice of the sign of the charge on the capacitor. So on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

The current through a resistor always goes from a high potential to a lower potential.

Starting at the bottom node and passing through the battery the potential increases, $+12 \,\rm V$.

The passing through the $100\,\Omega$ resistor the potential again increase, $+100\,I_3 \,\rm V$.

Then going through the $200\,\Omega$ resistor the potential decreases, $-200\,I_2 \,\rm V$.

That completes the clockwise loop and the sum must equal zero.